# Ignore first of the two divs with same class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a few URL that have 2 `divs` using same `class="description"`,

The source code of a sample URL is like this:

```
<!-- Initial HTML here -->

<div class="description">
<h4> Anonymous Title </h4>
<div class="product-description">
<li> Some stuff here </li>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Middle HTML here -->

<div class="description">
Some text here
</div>

<!-- Last HTML here -->
```

I'm **scraping** it using BeautifulSoap using following script

```
# imports etc here
description_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'description'})
description = description_box.text.strip()
print description
```

Running it gives me the first `div` with `class="description"` only however I want the second `div` with `class="description"` only.

Any ideas how I can ignore the first `div` and just scrape the second?

P.S. First `div` always have `h4` tags and second `div` only has plain text in between tags.

Comment: I'm curious why people always write something like ```soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'description'})``` instead of ```soup('div', 'description')```? Is this last syntax something implemented only on recent bs4? I'm using 4.6.3, BTW.

Comment: I'm new to Python and this is how most tutorials showed it. I tried your way and it works fine too.

Comment: Yeah! I notice that as well. I was asking because the latter is so much more readable. I'm wondering why people prefer the first form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `.find_all`, it'll return all in a list. It's then just a matter of selecting the 2nd item in that list using index 1:

```
html = '''<!-- Initial HTML here -->

<div class="description">
<h4> Anonymous Title </h4>
<div class="product-description">
<li> Some stuff here </li>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Middle HTML here -->

<div class="description">
Some text here
</div>

<!-- Last HTML here -->'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'description'})
div = divs[1]
```

**Output:**

```
print (div)
<div class="description">
Some text here
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please also have a look at my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400733/print-url-from-two-different-beautifulsoap-outputs

Answer (score 0):

Use `css-selector` as it contains the `nth-of-type` attribute to select the nth element of your specification. Also, syntax is cleaner.

```
description_box = soup.select("div.description:nth-of-type(2)")[0]
```

Comment: This returns a list, so you should probably use `description_box[0]` (edited in answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use type with class selector in css and index into returned collection

```
print(soup.select('div.description')[1].text)
```