# Print URL from two different BeautifulSoap outputs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a few URLs in batch using BeautifulSoap.

Here is my script (only relevant stuff):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = 'https://example.com/foo/bar'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
url_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'player'})
print url_box
```

This gives 2 different kinds of print depending on the HTML of URL (about half pages gives first print and rest give the second print).

Here's first kind of print:

```
<div class="player">
<video class="video-js vjs-fluid video-player" height="100%" id="some-player" poster="https://example.com/path/to/jpg/random.jpg" width="100%"></video>
<span data-type="trailer-src" data-url="https://example.com/path/to/mp4/random.mp4"></span>
</div>
```

And here's the other:

```
<div class="player">
<img alt="Image description here" src="https://example.com/path/to/jpg/random.jpg"/>
</div>
```

I want to extract the image URL which is `poster` in first and `src` in second.

Any ideas how I can do that so same script extracts that URL from either kind of print?

P.S The first print also has a mp4 link which I do not need.

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The question only contains absolutely relevant parts of code. Anything not related to the question is already removed.

Comment: Your question could get more attention if you, for example, had post the real URL. That way we could verify the code and give you better alternative snippets.

Comment: Since you are new on SO, I would suggest reading ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I want to keep my URLs anonymous as I have my reasons. It should be fairly obvious as I have obviously replaced them before posting the question.

Comment: OK. I'm not arguing. Those were just tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get()` method to get the value of attrs from the targeted tag.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
if url_box.find('video'):
    url = url_box.find('video').get('poster')
    mp4 = ulr_box.find('span').get('data-url')
if url_box.find('img'):
    url = url_box.find('img').get('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

Decide which version you are dealing with and split accordingly:

```py
firstVersion = '''<div class="player">
<video class="video-js vjs-fluid video-player" height="100%" id="some-player" poster="https://example.com/path/to/jpg/random.jpg" width="100%"></video>
<span data-type="trailer-src" data-url="https://example.com/path/to/mp4/random.mp4"></span>
</div>'''

secondVersion = '''<div class="player">
<img alt="Image description here" src="https://example.com/path/to/jpg/random.jpg"/>
</div>'''

def extractImageUrl(htmlInput):
    imageUrl = ""
    if "poster" in htmlInput:
        imageUrl = htmlInput.split('poster="')[1].split('"')[0]
    elif "src" in htmlInput:
        imageUrl = htmlInput.split('src="')[1].split('"')[0]
    return imageUrl
```